# MS Access single character cells

Tags: ms-access

In MS ACCESS is there is a way to discard records with only single character in a field, the cell have just A, or just b tried * and got all records, tried ? and got nothing
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LEN function in a query to say you only want the items of a given field greater then 1.

```
Select *
From TableName
Where LEN([FieldName]) > 1
```